# Onclick into Onclick not work ? (listener into listener)

Tags: android

I do click a image, and this image load a view, with more buttons, but I when click other button from other view, not response, why not response ?

```
imageViewPhotoSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        chooseOrTakePhoto();
    }
});
```

And I need click other button from other view, but not work.

```
 public void chooseOrTakePhoto() {
        final View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        LinearLayout lCancel = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.LCancel);

        lCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 // Here code not work !
             Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "work ?",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
 b.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null));
        b.create().show();
}
...
```

Xml

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/LCancel"
>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageViewPhotoSelect"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="88dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/photo"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your layout code for dialog_signin

Comment: where is your otherButton is initialised?

Comment: instead of using this, use "Activity.this" in dialog.

Comment: update code, i don't understand how listener into listener not work .

Comment: where is the method signature  `public void onClick(View v) {`? It is missing in both cases

Comment: StackOverflow not update code correctly sorry

Comment: It doesnt work because you're setting a clicklistener to the parent layout, when this one has a button inside. You either click on the whole layout or on specific things inside the layout. You could try setting android:descendantFocusability ="blocksDescendants" on your lCancel layout.

Comment: ok cool. You are inflating a new View in your chooseOrTakePhoto method. Is this view what you are showing in the Dialog?

Comment: I tried but not work ( android:descendantFocusability ="blocksDescendants"  ) , And yes I see dialog a sec put code

Comment: Any idea, about this problem.

Comment: Why do you have a nested linearlayout? As far as I can see, it does nothing ... And the second onClickListener is assigned to the parent of the imageView. It will not work because the parent is below the inflated dialog.

Answer (score 1):

It has to be like this:

```
otherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //your code here
    }
}
```

The second onClickListener is assigned to the parent of the imageView. It will not work because the parent is below the inflated dialog.

Comment: See again my code  - > OnClick { medthod(Onclick { Not work code}) }

Comment: @xaviergonzález show us the XML of the layout please.